# Exchange Server 2007 SP3, any caveats?

Tags: exchange-2007, service-pack

As per subject: can it be considered "safe" to apply this new service pack to live, production Exchange Server 2007 environments?

Did anyone already roll it out?

How did things go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while. I've installed it on lots of servers, and never had any problem at all.

Of course, this is quite outdated a question now... anyway, that's my experience with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even if I consider it safe to my live environment (I haven't yet, still evaluating and testing) that doesn't mean it's safe to apply to your environment. Create a test environment and check would be my advice.

Comment: Of course this is what I'll be doing :-) But I'd like to hear opinions from people who may already have tested and/or applied it.

Comment: While I agree with the answer, I think this question is important to the ones that don't have the ability to setup a test environment.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it on our 1 live production exchange server and so far no problems that I can tell.  Out Of Office settings are still sometimes not updated with the most current information when the client turns it on, but other than that no glaring problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that "Out Of Office settings are still sometimes not updated"? Is it a probleam you were already having that was not resolved by SP3, or did it begin after applying it?

Comment: It's a problem that has been around way before SP3, but I believe it is more closely related to using Outlook 2003 with Exchange 2007.  Outlook 2003 does not support the extended Out-Of-Office capabilities that Exchange 2007 has. It sometimes it works for my users through Outlook 2003, sometimes it does not.  If you set the Out of Office using OWA, then it always works.